# Ordenamiento por mezcla, consulta sobre como funciona. [python]

Tags: python, poo

hago el copy paste de mi codigo:

```
def ordenamiento_por_merzcla(lista):
    if len(lista) > 1:
        medio = len(lista) // 2
        izquierda = lista[:medio]
        derecha = lista[medio:]
        #LLAMADA RECURSIVA EN CADA MITAD
        ordenamiento_por_merzcla(izquierda)
        ordenamiento_por_merzcla(derecha)
        
        
        # ITERADORES PARA RECORRER LAS DOS SUBLISTAS
        i = 0
        j = 0
        # iterador para la lista principal
        k = 0

        while i < len(izquierda) and j < len(derecha):
            if izquierda[i] < derecha [j]:
                lista[k] = izquierda[i]
                i+= 1
            else:
                lista[k] = derecha[j]
                j += 1
            
            k+= 1
        
        while i < len(izquierda):
            lista [k] = izquierda[i]
            i  += 1
            k +=1

        while j < len(derecha):
            lista [k] = derecha[j]
            j +=1
            k +=1

    return lista
```

La parte donde me confundo, es en donde asigna el valor **izquierda = lista[:medio] y derecha= lista[medio:]**

Pongo de ejemplo que tengo una Lista de 6 valores: [10,6,8,2,3,7]

1. medio = 3
2. izquierda = 10,6,8
3. derecha = 2,3,7
4. **RECURSIVIDAD** de izquierda
5. medio = 2
6. izquierda = 10,6 ????? no entiendo esta parte, donde quedaría el 8 ?

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: ala nueva derecha.. si partiste en 2, y estas solo en esa mitad, el 8 es tu nueva derecha...

Comment: Pero la derecha no contiene 2,3,7 ???

Answer (score 0):

En el paso

```
5. medio = 2
```

lo correcto es

```
5. medio = 1
```

Esta es la secuencia de llamadas del código:

```
[10,6,8,2,3,7]
  izquierda [10, 6, 8]
    izquierda [10]
    derecha [6, 8]
      izquierda [6]
      derecha [8]

  derecha [2, 3, 7]
    izquierda [2]
    derecha [3, 7]
      izquierda [3]
      derecha [7]
```

Comment: Perfecto! Pero mi confusión empieza en izquierda = lista[:medio] porque al aplicar recursividad la lista izquierda, cambia de valor.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo, que lo que te sucede es que no comprendes el slicing (si no es así hazmelo saber, para borrar la respuesta). Partiendo de tu ejemplo:

> Pongo de ejemplo que tengo una Lista de 6 valores: [10,6,8,2,3,7]
>
> - medio = 3
> - izquierda = 10,6,8
> - derecha = 2,3,7
> - RECURSIVIDAD de izquierda
> - medio = 2
> - izquierda = 10,6 ????? no entiendo esta parte, donde quedaría el 8 ?
> - Gracias de antemano!!

Lo que está sucediendo es lo siguiente.

### Cuando medio es igual a tres.

```
medio = 3
lista = [10,6,8,2,3,7]
```

Cogemos hasta el valor **ocho** inclusive, porque esta operación `izquierda = lista[:medio]` significa, coge todos los valores hasta el valor de medio, en este caso es **tres** por lo que coges el 10, 6, 8. Es decir **los tres primeros números** en la izquierda.

Despues haces: `derecha = lista[medio:]` por lo que coges de la **tercera posición en adelante** esto te da el 2, 3, 4

### Cuando medio es igual a dos

Las operaciones son las mismas, pero has cambiado el valor de medio, en este caso es dos, por lo que sucederá lo siguiente:

```
medio = 2
izquierda = lista[:medio]
```

Aquí le acabamos de decir a la lista que coja todos los valores hasta la segunda posición incluida, por lo que coge 10, 6.

Cuando hagamos la siguiente operación `derecha = lista[medio:]` nos cogerá todas las posiciones a partir de la segunda. El resultado será 8, 2, 3, 7. Por lo que el **ocho** habrá pasado al lado derecho.

## Resumen.

Esta técnica se llama **slicing** y es super importante en Python. **Se basa en los indices** para poder extraer datos de listas, y ahorra muchísimo tiempo a la hora de programar.

Comment: Hola! Excelente tu explicacion, muchas gracias! Quizas no me explico bien yo, cuando la recursividad termina, cada nunero donde esta almacenado? Esa es mi confucion, perdon por ser un poco dura.

Comment: Xq cuando termina la recursividad izquierda pasa a tener 10. Solamente, no?